# Difference in count of groupby and its indices

Tags: pandas

What is the difference between the lenght of groupby object and the length of indices method of groupby object? I expected to return the same numbers for both the statements.

```
len(Fees.groupby(['InstituteCode','Code','ProgramType','Status','AcademicYear']))
8000
```

Why do I get different numbers?

```
len(Fees.groupby(['InstituteCode','Code','ProgramType','Status','AcademicYear']).indices)
7433
```

Does it mean I have only 7433 distinct records for the given list of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because the "Code" column was **null** for 568 records. Those were skipped in groupby. It became clear when I checked for null values using...

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().sum())
```